# mysql query returns list of list of matched elements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
Products ::=
  id         int,
  category   varchar,
  line       varchar,
  type       varchar,
  marketType enum('first','second')
```

What I want to do is find the list of `id`s of all the *products* with same `category`, `line`, `type`; `line` could also be `NULL` or the empty string.

Example:

```
+------+----------+--------+------+
|   id | category |   line | type |
+------+----------+--------+------+
|  123 |        1 | qwerty |    X |
|  534 |        1 | qwerty |    X |
|   90 |        1 | qwerty |    Z |
|  666 |        2 | qwerty |    Z |
|  444 |        2 | qwerty |    Z |
| 1616 |        2 | qwerty |    Z |
|  921 |        2 |        |    X |
|   16 |        2 |        |    X |
+------+----------+--------+------+
```

The result I want to accomplish is a list in which every element is a list of the matched `id`s:

```
123, 534
90
666, 444, 1616
921, 16
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use MySQL's [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function when grouping your table by the columns that are equal in each group:

```
SELECT   GROUP_CONCAT(id)
FROM     Products
GROUP BY category, line, type
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25761/1/0).